# How to perform fine grained access control in an asp.net MVC application.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

How is everyone else performing fine grained access control in an MVC app? i.e. a user may be related to multiple objects and have different access requirements to each object. Can this be achieved using asp.net identity claims / roles? or do I have to role out my own?

Is there any design pattern I can follow if I need to roll out my own?

Answer (score 0):

No doubt there are plenty of ways to do this, but asp.net-mvc leads itself to extensibility of the AuthorizeAttribute, eg:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class ActionPermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Override OnAuthorization, not AuthorizeCore as AuthorizeCore will force user login prompt rather than inform the user of the issue.
        var controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        bool authorised = ... // Check permissions here
        if (!authorised)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("You are not authorised to perform this action.");

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

this can be applied to the controller (or as base controller) so doesn't need to be on every single action.

The actual check permissions can be as simple or complicated as you want - eg store controller + action + active directory group in a database will allow the permissions to be changed dynamically.